# Iframe doesn't show up on Chrome within Masonry CSS grid

Tags: html, css, iframe, masonry

I've just noticed that when you create a CSS based masonry using `column-width` and put an iframe into it, The iframe doesn't show up in Chrome, however it works fine in other browsers.
Is that a known bug in Chrome or lack of my code?
Here is my HTML

```
<section>
  <div class='block'>
    <img src='../images/mockup/jpg/1.jpg'>
  </div>
</section>
```

And here is the CSS

```
section {
  -moz-column-width: 15em;
  -webkit-column-width: 15em;
  column-width: 15em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
```

Check the live version on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/smwc8sex/show/)

Comment: The div surrounding the iframe isn't closed - fix that, and it should work.

Comment: @Niffler It's not the case, however i updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/smwc8sex/1/show/

Comment: Sorry, I tested it before and I thought that did it... I think the problem is the script that's added right after the iframe; I removed that, and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/md6jqzm4/show/ (Not very nicely when you hover over it, but I think that's an issue of the iframe itself...)